# git rebase 'magic' needed to keep commit history

Tags: git

How do I do get from:

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- F - G - H
                     \             /  \
feature:               A' - B' - C'     D' - F' - G'
```

to:

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- F - G - H
                     \             /          \
feature:               A' - B' - C'            D' - F' - G'
```

? Basically removing the A'-C'-F history, doing a rebase of D'-G' from F to H, then adding it back. It would be SO USEFUL.

Here are more details on why I want this. I use a feature branch when I work. 
My workflow:

```
master: A - B - C - D
             \    
feature:      A' - B' - C'
```

When I'm done with my feature, i do `git rebase master` then either `git rebase -i master`, or from master `git merge --squash feature` and then push it to master as one nice commit.

I get:

```
master: A - B - C - D - F
                     \    
feature:              A' - B' - C'
```

Where F is just A', B', and C' squashed together.
All is good. But then I want to continue working on the same feature branch. I haven't figured out how to do it. I could do:

```
feature2:                  D' - E' - F'
                         / 
master: A - B - C - D - F
                     \    
feature(archive):      A' - B' - C'
```

Which is annoying. Doing merge --squash then merging master and feature would get:

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- F - G - H
                     \             /  \
feature:               A' - B' - C'     D' - F' - G'
```

Help me get to this:

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- F - G - H
                     \             /          \
feature:               A' - B' - C'            D' - F' - G'
```

So then I could push to master like:

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- F - G - H ------------ I
                     \             /          \            /
feature:               A' - B' - C'            D' - F' - G'
```

and repeat the cycle.

Last figure, for a comment.

```
master: A - B - C - D -------------- merge - F - G - H
                     \              /    \
feature:               A' - B' - C' ---- merge - D' - F' - G'`
```

Comment: nicely formatted question! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overthinking things. Your first example is easily done simply by doing `git rebase master` on the feature branch. The `A' B' C'` bit is common history, so rebase ignores it.

The problem may be that you're squashing to create `F`. If you want to keep `A' - B' - C'` in the history, don't squash - just `git merge`. If you want to get rid of the intermediate commits, well, go ahead and squash, but then you have to throw away those commits and `git reset --hard master` on the feature branch to get back to a history that can be merged with the master.

Comment: That's my problem. How do I squash and keep my history (without archiving a branch)?It just doesn't make sense to have every small commit I make go to master.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either get rid of history or keep it - if you get rid of history, you also get rid of the information needed to perform further merges. You may want to look at `rebase -i` to clean up your history before merging back (squashing changes into logical steps).

Comment: Is there any way to have it go both ways? It would be awesome for master to have stable&logical commits, but to be able to keep the details for myself.

Comment: Your desire to *push* to `master` only when things are stable does not require you to squash your commit history -- indeed, it's better to push several smaller, descriptive commits, as *other* developers as well as yourself can then better understand your work. This does not sacrifice stability, as `git fetch` will still pull all of your commits if you pushed all of them to `master` at once.

Comment: @Blair Holloway. I believe that *every* single state/commit on master should compile. If it doesn't, then it's not useful for anybody. And even though I agree with smaller descriptive comments being helpful, it's stupid to take a min to write descriptive stuff when you commit every 10 min or less (which you should btw).

Comment: Why are you keeping commits that don't compile? You're just breaking `git bisect` for yourself

Answer (score 1):

The [OP Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486315/mihai) comments:

> Is there any way to have it go both ways? It would be awesome for master to have stable & logical commits, but to be able to keep the details for myself.

Why yes, there is in theory (Even though [Blair Holloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230575/blair-holloway) already gave compelling reason to not to ;) ).
You need to remember that Git never change/erase/override the history of commits. It only make *new* ones.

So if:

- instead to rebase/merge squashing your `feature` branch, you rebase or merge a **`feature-tmp`** branch (that you create where `feature` is), you will still have the `feature` branch in place!
  (because the `features` HEAD would still reference those "old" commits before and rebase or squash)
- then you would `git checkout feature` (which is still there), and `git merge -s ours master` back to `feature` (that way and subsequent merge or rebase will only consider features commits from *after* that first rebase or merge)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your solution doesn't work. See the last last figure in my post (as I can't draw it here).
In this I had the feature-tmp (containing A'B'C') merged in as F into master. Then I imediately merged back with `merge -s ours master`. Here, I can't do anything without merge errors.

Comment: @Mihai: the idea is to use `feature-tmp` for rebase or squash from `feature` (which would still exist) to `master`. But right after that, you would need to **`git checkout feature`** (not `feature-tmp`), and `merge -s ours master` in order to record on `feature` what has already been integrated to `master`.